# Problema al usar autocomplete, Jquery-ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La información me la trae correctamente ya verifique por `consola`, mi problema es, porque me salen esas *lineas* como si quisiera mostrar la información pero no tiene nada, alguien sabe que esta pasando?.

```
$('#auto_tag').autocomplete({
    source: function(request,response){
        $.ajax({
            url: uri+'/tags',
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            data:{keys: request.term},
            success: function(data){
                response(data);
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 1,
    select: function(event,ui){
        data = ui.item.id+'*'+ui.item.name;
        $('#button-a-tag').val(data);
    },
});
```

Comment: Pasa que está intentando mostrar resultados del autocompletado pero al no existir información (la busqueda de "v" arroja cero resultados) entonces cada fila resultado del autocomplete se "llena" con un valor vacio. Por las filas con espacios en blanco

Comment: Deberías realizar un chequeo en tu success de la información y si esta viene vacia arrojar un alert o como quieras donde notifiques al usuario que el valor ingresado no ha retornado resultados coincidentes

Comment: Si esta filtrando. El `log` me trae información al escribir como debe ser, el problema que no muestra los resultado, solo arroja esas lineas

Comment: Habría que ver el archivo de backend donde envias la información en formato json a la vista. Probablemente no estés haciendo correctamente el "echo" de la información de tu autocomplete

Comment: Solucione mi problema, asignando `as label` en mi consulta a la columna de búsqueda. Gracias!

Comment: De nada. Me alegra que ya solucionaste, Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Tenia el mismo problema, en mi caso fue que la acción que me devolvía los elementos a mostrar en el autocomplete tenia un mal formato. Dicho "formato" se le puede dar en el Select(). no se como explicarlo, pero te pongo el código de como devuelvo la info.

```
var resultado = db.TBL_PRODUCTOS.Where(x => x.DESCRIPCION.Contains(term)).Where(x => x.ESTATUS == true).Select(x => new { label = x.DESCRIPCION, value = x.DESCRIPCION+"|"+x.ID_PRODUCTO }).ToArray();
            return Json(resultado, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Uso expresiones lambda para mis consultas, en el Select cree un objeto anónimo y lo mas importante es que debe tener una propiedad que se llame LABEL y otra que se llame VALUE. Donde LABEL es la sugerencia de autocomplete y VALUE es con lo que se llenara tu textbox

Dándole ese "formato" corregí el error.

Espero y te sirva. por cierto es la primera vez que publico.